# как заменить месяц на его числовое обозначение

Tags: c

Как заменить числовое значение месяца на его буквенный аналог в си? К примеру: 12 - DEC, 11 - NOV

Comment: заменить где? Воспользуйтесь switch..case

Comment: Как вариант, объявить массив `const char* month[] = {"", "JAN", "FEB", ...};`, тогда `i`-тый элемент массива будет хранить строковое представление `i`-того месяца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char * monthName(int no) {
    const char M[] = { "JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN",
                       "JUL","AUG","SE","OCT","NOV","DEC" }
    return (no >= 1 && no <= 12) ? M[no-1] : "UNK";
    }
```