# Почему не выводится ошибка связанная с переменной MIN_YEAR и MAX_YEAR?

Tags: c

````
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN_YEAR 2010
#define MAX_YEAR 2021

int main() {
    const int JAN = 1, DEC = 12;
    int year, month;


    printf("General Well-being Log\n");
    printf("======================\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Set the year and mounth the well-being log (YYYY MM): ");
    

    while(1) {

        printf("Set the year and mounth the well-being log (YYYY MM): ");
        scanf("%d %d", &year, &month);

        if (year < MIN_YEAR && year > MAX_YEAR) {
            printf("ERROR: The year must be between 2010 and 2021 inclusive\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if (month < 1 || month >12) {
            printf("ERROR: Jan.(1) - Dec.(12)\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if (year < MIN_YEAR && year > MAX_YEAR && month < 1 || month >12) {
            printf("ERROR: The year must be between 2010 and 2021 inclusive\n");
            printf("ERROR: Jan.(1) - Dec.(12)\n");
            continue;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
        
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("*** Log date set! ***\n");
    printf("\n");
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-JAN-01\n", year);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-FEB-01\n", year);
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-MAR-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-APR-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-MAY-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-JUN-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 7:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-JUL-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 8:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-AUG-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-SEP-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 10:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-OCT-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 11:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-NOV-01\n", year);
        break;
    case 12:
        printf("Log starting date: %d-DEC-01\n", year);
        break;
    }





return 0;
}```

почему не выводится ошибка связанная с переменной MIN_YEAR и MAX_YEAR?
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скажите, а как вы себе представляете число, которое одновременно меньше 2010, и больше 2021?

```
year < MIN_YEAR && year > MAX_YEAR
```

Может, все же - или?

```
year < MIN_YEAR || year > MAX_YEAR
```

И, конечно, не мое дело - но что вы такие `switch`-макароны развесили? Был же недавно ответ, как месяц получить по номеру...

Вот, [нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1239633/195342) -

```
const char * monthName(int no) {
    const char M[] = { "JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN",
                       "JUL","AUG","SE","OCT","NOV","DEC" }
    return (no >= 1 && no <= 12) ? M[no-1] : "UNK";
    }
```

и весь ваш `switch` превращается в

```
printf("Log starting date: %d-%s-01\n", year, monthName(month));
```

Comment: @Domestos Поставьте галочку слева от ответа чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.